# Broken iPhone 5s screen, can't authorize iTunes

Tags: iphone

I have recently damaged my iPhone 5s screen and have had to buy a new phone. I'm trying to backup the damaged device to my computer and iTunes is asking me to authorize access to my iPhone, which I can't because the screen is not responding.
Is there a workaround?

Comment: im trying to backup the damaged one*

Comment: no Touch ID set up? Thumbprint will work, if so.

Comment: While not specifically mentioned whether it was shut down or not, Touch ID will only work when the phone was unlocked by the passcode once after shut down.  Seeing that he bought a new phone, there is a chance the old phone may have laid in standby in the meantime running out of juice.

Comment: Personally, if feasible for you, I would bring it to a store and specifically have the screen repaired.  If they have the parts and are not too busy, the fitting time once your phone is worked on is about 1-2 hours (or less).  While a backup is always recommended when having a hardware serviced, to my knowledge they do not restore the phone to replace the screen.  Ask the store when contacting them.  Repairing the screen will normally not be free of charge, but should be way less than having a phone serviced, let alone buying a new one.

Comment: If you're up for it, a front panel replacement is [something you could attempt yourself](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+5s+Front+Panel+Replacement/22096) as well. Given that it's a deceased phone, there's not all too much you can destroy in terms of screen connectors. If it's really just the glass, you can get it for a few dollars on ebay. What's broken, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Ask Apple if there is a store near by. Usually they charge $129 (plus tax) to fix a broken iPhone 5s screen. If you can't get to an Apple store, you can mail your device in to Apple for a shipping fee of $6.95. If you purchased AppleCare+ ($99 for two years) for your device, you'll only have to pay $79 for a screen repair -- though AppleCare+ only covers two incidents of accidental damage. If you don't have Applecare+ you can choose a reliable supplier to buy a screen replacement and then do the repair by yourself or a repair man.